# How to make SELECT NEXT VALUE work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, syntax-error, porting

I'm having some difficulties trying to get the following to work in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE table_X AS
    SELECT 
        NEXT VALUE FOR GROUP_A AS GROUP_ID, RISK_ID
    FROM 
        ( SELECT UNIQUE RISK_ID, FROM table_Y ) SS;
```

I am told:

```
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'."
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'."
```

What exactly is the problem and how can I fix this to work in `SQL Server`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `create table as` syntax is not SQL Server syntax.  It uses `select ... into` to create a table from a query.

Comment: could you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: `NEXT VALUE FOR` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx

Comment: I am trying to port this statement to SQL Server.  I'm not yet familiar with how to port something like this so I am quite confused. This is my first porting experience so sorry if I seem like a moron.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
FirstName Varchar(50),
LastName Varchar(50)
);

/*
Insert Some Values Into Person
*/

CREATE SEQUENCE CountBy
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR CountBy OVER (ORDER BY LastName) AS ListNumber,
    FirstName, LastName
    INTO table_x
FROM Person
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    NEXT VALUE FOR GROUP_A AS GROUP_ID, SS.RISK_ID
INTO
    table_X 
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT RISK_ID FROM table_Y ) SS
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.table_X') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.table_X

SELECT RISK_ID --, ..... columns
INTO dbo.table_X
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT RISK_ID 
    FROM dbo.table_Y 
) SS

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table_X
```